# a simple filtering language that can be embedded in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, filter, filtering

I have a ruby project where part of the operation is to select entities given user-specified constraints. So far, I've been hacking my own filter language, using regular expressions and specifying inclusion/exclusion based on the fields in the entities.

If you are interested in my current approach, here's an example: For instance, given this list of entities:

`[{"type":"dog", "name":"joe"}, {"type":"dog", "name":"fuzz"}, {"type":"cat", "name":"meow"}]`

A user could specify a filter like so:

`{"filter":{
  "type":{"included":["dog"]  },
  "name":{"excluded":["^f.*"] }
}}`

Would match all dogs but exclude fuzz.

This is sort of working now. However, I am starting to require more sophisticated selection parameters. I am thinking that rather than continuing to hack on my own filter language, there might be a more general-purpose filter language I can just embed in my application? For instance, is there a parser that can in-app filter using a SQL `where` clause? Or are there some other general, simple filter languages that I'm not aware of? I would especially like to move away from regexps since I want to do range querying on numbers (like is entity["size"] < 50 ?)

Comment: after some googling around, i discovered LINQ in C#, which might have ruby equivalents: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, i ended up implementing a ruby dsl. it's easy, fun, and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit of an extrapolation, but I think you *may* be looking for a search engine, or at least enough of one that you may as well use one just for the query language.

If so you might want to look at [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) which does have Ruby client bindings, and *could* be a good fit for what you are trying to do. Especially if you want or need to express the data you want to search as JSON for use by client code, as that format is natively supported by the search engine.

The query language is quite expressive, and there are a variety of built-in and plugin tools available to explore and use it.